# How to find limit of $f(x)= \frac{x^9 + 4 \exp(0.6 x)}{3 x^{12} + 2 \exp(0.6 x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f(x)= \frac{x^9 + 4 \exp(0.6 x)}{3 x^{12} + 2 \exp(0.6 x)}$$

At first, I took out the dominant terms and reduced to $2\exp(0.6x)$ and assumed the limit going to negative infinity was zero and positive infinity was infinity. However, when graphing I can see that the limit going to positive infinity is 2. How can I find the limit algebraically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in your calculations

> At first, I took out the dominant terms and reduced to $2\exp(0.6x)$

If we ignore the polynomial terms in your limit (which are inconsequential, as you note) we get
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^9 + 4 \exp(0.6 x)}{3 x^{12} + 2 \exp(0.6 x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4 \exp(0.6 x)}{2 \exp(0.6 x)}$$
At this point you forgot that the $\exp(0.6x)$ is in *both* the numerator and denominator, and thus they cancel out
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4 \exp(0.6 x)}{2 \exp(0.6 x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4}{2}=2$$

Answer (score 1):

By L'hopital's rule,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^n}{\exp(0.6x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{0.6^n\exp(0.6x)}=0$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^9 + 4 \exp(0.6 x)}{3 x^{12} + 2 \exp(0.6 x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^9\exp(-0.6 x) + 4 }{3 x^{12}\exp(-0.6 x) + 2}=\frac{0+4}{0+2}=2$$